# Lenovo laptops becoming very slow after locking

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

We have end users who are experiencing slow Windows performance after returning to a locked machine. If the user lets the computer self-lock (sleep) there is no issue when they return. If the end user manually locks the machine then unlocks it the machine is very slow to open applications or run browser tabs. A restart fixes the issue, but isn't a great solution. I have an idea that our Lenovo Vantage updates are causing the issue, but not 100% sure. Computers are running v1909 with all the latest updates from WSUS.

Comment: No issue here with 2 Lenovo laptops (one production 20H2 and one Insder 21H newest).  Update all Drivers (System Update) and then run Vantage to update it (there are updates).  Restart and test the computers.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the power management firmware that Vantage installed. No proof, just a hunch.

Comment: Make sure all the drivers are up to date. Set Threshold as you wish. Does not affect speed. The only other setting is always on USB. No issue here but try turning it off

Comment: And by the way the firmware for Vantage is BIOS so update that and Management Engine Firmware.

Answer (score 1):

1. control panel > power options > choose what closing the lid does > change settings that are currently unavailable > uncheck fast startup > save settings
2. right click on desktop > display settings > Advanced scaling settings > turn off  "Let Windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry
3. left click battery icon on the lower right of the desktop > drag the bar to "Best performance"

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a Docking Station / Port Replicator, updating the DisplayLink Driver may help to resolve the issue (https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/windows)

Answer (score -2):

Had the same issue and managed to resolve this by running the Lenovo System Update and forcing a BIOS update